# Webpack loader aliases?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I have a fairly complicated loader setup for style sheets:

```
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style",
      "css?sourceMap&localIdentName=[path][name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]!sass?outputStyle=expanded&" +
      "includePaths[]=" + other stuff)
    )
  }
```

Which works great, but on some requires I want to add the `modules` option to css-loader, so it'd look like this:

```
require('./foo.scss!css?modules&sourceMap&localIdentName=[path][name]__[local]__[hash...');
```

But I can't do this all over the place.

How can I configure this so that I can enable the css-loader modules flag on certain requires while keeping the rest of it the same?

Maybe something like a loader 'alias', e.g. `require('./foo.scss!my-scss-with-modules-flag-alias')`?

The only solution I can think of is writing a loader that does a syntax transform to inline the loader config into certain require calls... but that's brittle and complicated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

resolveLoader.alias will work here. Ie.

```
resolveLoader: {
    alias: {
        'with-modules': 'loader definition goes here',
    }
}
```

Using this configuration you can do simply

```
require('with-modules!./foo.scss');
```

at your code.

Comment: How did you get to this solution? Webpack is amazing, bug I am having a hard time with the documentation ...

Comment: Well, I'm authoring webpack related books so it's sort of my job to know these things. I did add a note about this to the documentation as it was missing earlier. I agree the documentation can be a bit opaque.

Comment: @JuhoVepsäläinen: Can you expand on your answer. What would go in the definition?
If I try to create an alias with "style!css?modules!postcss", I get an error: Cannot resolve module 'style!css'.

Comment: @JacobT.Nielsen As far as I understand, you can alias just a loader name, not a chain like that. I tried aliasing a chain a while ago and it failed. I even opened an issue about that as it would be handy.

Answer (score 1):

The resolveLoader.alias might work in the given case, since you are using a plugin as the loader.
However if you need to use a chain of loaders, it will not work. (There's a feature request on it: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2772).

Instead you can add a parameter to the file in the require statement

```
var styles = require('./foo.scss?modules');
```

And create a new loader rule:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        ...
        { test: /\.scss$/, loader: 'style!css!postcss!sass' },
        { test: /\.scss\?modules$/, loader: 'style!css?modules!postcss!sass' }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Couldn't get this to work using Webpack 3. It always selected the first loader as if it was ignoring the query params.