# Using a text loader in Webpack for RequireJS text plugin

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, webpack

So my AngularJS code looks like this:

```
define(['angular', 'text!./template.html'], function (angular, template) {
'use strict';

return angular.module('app.widget', [])
    .directive('MyWidget', function(){
         //.... use the template here
})
```

I'm using the text plugin for RequireJS to get the html template and use in in the AngularJS directive. 
I want to use webpack and it's reading the AMD style code ok but it can't work with the text plugin.

Does anyone know how to get the text-loader for webpack to work with requirejs?
There are [some solutions out there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31948152/requirejs-text-plugin-alternative-to-webpack) and a [discussion thread](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1046) but I can't get them to work.

In my webpack.config.js I've got

```
loaders: [
  { test: /^text\!/, loader: "text" }
]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install `raw-loader`, which is the webpack equivalent for loading raw files

```
npm i raw-loader
```

Then you need to alias the requireJS style with the `raw-loader` (resolveLoader is to be put in the root of the webpack config object)

```
resolveLoader: {
    alias: {
        'text': {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: "raw-loader"
            },
    }
}
```

Check this SO question:  [Webpack loader aliases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31313088/webpack-loader-aliases)

Answer (score 4):

Actually you need dont need to specify node modules path. It works if you specify just the name of the actual loader like below

```
resolveLoader: {
        alias: { "text": "text-loader" }
    },
```

Comment: Webpack no longer supports the answer's syntax - this solution worked for me

Comment: Worked for my in Webpack version 3+. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A similar solution which worked for me with Webpack 2.2:

```
resolveLoader: {
    alias: {
        // Support for require('text!file.json').
        'text': 'full/path/to/node_modules/text-loader'
    }
}
```

And install text-loader:

```
npm install text-loader
```